# First truthy function result assignment with Lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, functional-programming, lodash

Context of a world of JS [lodash](https://lodash.com)

Currently I am trying to achieve with ease analog of multiple OR statements assignment.
Usually we do something like this:

```
let myOption = argumentAssigned || tryToGetFromOtherSource('sourceA') || tryToGetFromOtherSource('sourceB');
```

for success I'd like to have something like:

```
let myOption = _.X(
    argumentAssigned,
    _.partial(tryToGetFromOtherSource, 'sourceA'),
    _.partial(tryToGetFromOtherSource, 'sourceB') );
```

and of course do not execute further functions if previous brings truthy result.

Comment: something like `function X(ret, ...args) {
    while(!ret && args.length) ret = (args.shift())();
    return ret;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's in lodash, but you can write this function yourself. I chose to pass an argument along; if the functions don't take an argument there doesn't seem to be a point in lazy-evaluating them (since they'd either be impure or just constants).

```js
const firstTruthy = ([f, ...fs], x) =>
  f ? f(x) || firstTruthy(fs, x) : null;


// Example app
const repo1 = k => ({ "a": 1 })[k];
const repo2 = k => ({ "b": 2 })[k];

const getKey = k => firstTruthy([repo1, repo2], k);

console.log(getKey("a"));
console.log(getKey("b"));
console.log(getKey("c"));
```